# setTimeout() in a loop does not wait 3 seconds between each call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, settimeout

I'm trying to access an API to pull stock data. The free plan only lets me make 5 calls per minute. I'm trying to use native JS/jQuery to make the calls. Using some example code I'll illustrate my issue (using 3 second intervals). I initially thought that putting `setTimeout()` within a for-loop that prints to the console would print, wait 3 seconds, print, wait 3 seconds, repeat... But what it does is wait 3 seconds, and then prints all the lines at once. I understand this now. It seems bad practice to "lock up" execution of a program, but I'm starting to think that is what needs to be done here?

```
$(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        doSetTimeout(i);
    }
});

function doSetTimeout(i) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 3000);
}
```

I also tried "locking up" the program with a while-loop and time delay. But my entire browser just froze and became unresponsive for much longer than the time inputted.

```
function pauseExecution(miliseconds) {
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
     while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
     }
}
```

Comment: setTimeOut is asynchronious, don't expect of simple loop for that

Comment: When you call `setTimeout()`, it tells the browser to run that function in the future (after X milliseconds).  You've added 5 timeouts, all at 3000ms, so that's when they all run.  You either need to a) run `setTimeout()` _inside_ the timeout's callback to add a new one, b) do `setTimeout(function(){}, 3000*i)` to set all 5, but have them run at different times, or c) use `var myInterval = setInterval(function(){}, 3000)` to have the function run every 3000ms (until you call `clearInterval(myInterval);`).

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, `setTimeout` is async. What is happening is you are scheduling `5` tasks to complete after roughly `3000ms`. What you should do is not queue another task until the previous one has completed. This can be achieved in about a million way.

#### Async/Await

If you can, just use `async/await`. Its the easiest with the least amount of code.

```js
const delay = (ms) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
  }, ms);
};

$(async function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    await delay(3000);
    console.log(i);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Promise

Creating a promise chain where every task is dependent on a `delay` and a `unit of work` would serve a similar purpose as `async/await` if you are not transpiling ect. You have to be careful with `catch`ect to make this production ready.

```js
const delay = (ms) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
  }, ms);
};

$(function() {
  let task = delay(3000);
  const work = (i) => console.log(i);

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let j = i; // you need this because of closures.
    
    task = task
      .finally(() => {
        work(j); 
      })
      .then(() => delay(3000));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Queues

This is probably the most complex solution. You create a `blocking queue`. All tasks can be queued whenever but the queue will only execute the next task after the current task calls `next`. This is not production ready and is meant to serve as an example. There are issues with stack overflows with sync operations as well as exception handling.

```js
const queue = () => {
  const tasks = [];
  let running = false;
  
  const add = (task) => {
    tasks.push(task);
    run();
  };
  
  const run = () => {
    if (!running) {
      running = true;
      
      const step = () => {
        if (tasks.length > 0) {
          tasks.shift()(step);
        } else {
          console.log('done');
          running = false;
        }
      };
      
      step();
    };
  };
  
  return { add, run };
};

const q = queue();

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  q.add((next) => {
    const j = i; // again because of closure scoping.
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(j);
      next();
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

#### SetInterval

If you dont need to block on previous operations(ajax/fetch) you could simply use a `setInterval`. This just schedules a task evey `N`ms regardless of the state of the previous tasks.

```js
let i = 0;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (i === 5) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
    console.log(i++);
  }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ohh I have already done something like that, What you need to do is run and wait for the func to end.

See this example to understand.

```js
function doSomthing(){
console.log("Somthing is done");
Start();
}

function Start(){
 setTimeout(doSomthing, 3000);
}

Start();
```

Comment: I really like this. It's elegant